# Returning false if the input to my string test function is empty

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I am doing a problem set to find a the number of occurrences for `"x"` and `"o"`, case insensitive and return true if they occur the same amount of times in the string and false otherwise. The problem set has a couple of edge cases, some of which I have solved, but this one edge case persists.

```
Empty string contains equal amount of x and o - Expected: true, instead got: false
```

Here is the code:

```
function XO(str) {
    //code here

    var res_x = str.match(/x/gi)
    var res_o = str.match(/o/gi)
    if (res_o !== null && res_x !== null) 
    {
      res = (res_o.length) == (res_x.length)?true:false

    } else if (res_o == "" || res_x == "") {

      res = true

    } else if (res_o == "" && res_x == "") {

      res = true

    } else if (res_o == null && res_x == null) {
        res = false
    } else {

      res = false

    }



    return res

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This logic here is overcomplicated. Excessive branching and booleans make the program difficult to understand. The edge cases are pretty much imaginary--an empty string doesn't require any special logic from longer strings.

Here's a possible approach: remove all of the `"x"` characters from the string and take the length. Remove all of the `"o"` characters from the string and take the length. Return true if the lengths after removals are the same. Empty string will be handled because `"".length === "".length`.

```js
const xo = s => s.replace(/x/gi, "").length === s.replace(/o/gi, "").length;

[
  "",
  "xo",
  "oxox",
  "xxoo",
  "xoo",
  "oxx",
  "x",
  "o",
  "oxxox"
].forEach(e => console.log(xo(e)));
```

Checking for `null` is not something that's typically done in JS--you can simply let an exception be thrown if the caller breaks the (implicit) contract by doing something silly like calling the function with a nonsense value.

If you *have* to do this, you can use `try`/`catch`:

```js
const xo = s => {
  try {
    return s.replace(/x/gi, "").length === s.replace(/o/gi, "").length;
  }
  catch {
    return false;
  }
};

[  
  42,
  {},
  [],
  null,
  undefined,
  "",
  "xo",
  "oxox",
  "xxoo",
  "xoo",
  "oxx",
  "x",
  "o",
  "oxxox"
].forEach(e => console.log(xo(e)));
```

It might also be worth considering that this function could/should be generalized to accept any characters as parameters instead of hard coding it to work on only `"x"` and `"o"`. Something like:

```js
const balanced = s => {
  const frequencies = Object.values([...s].reduce((a, e) => {
    a[e] = ++a[e] || 1;
    return a;
  }, {}));
  return frequencies.every(e => e === frequencies[0]);
};

[  
  "",
  "xo",
  "oxox",
  "xxoo",
  "abc",
  "acbd",
  "x",
  "o"
].forEach(e => console.log(balanced(e)));
```